# Error with dbatools

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting, automation, dbatools

Trying to export SQL Objects via DBAtools in Powershell.

```
 Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance 'TestServer01' -Job 'mydatabase-daily-backup' | Export-DbaScript -FilePath C:\temp\mydatabase-daily-backup.sql
```

The same script working fine and exporting the job details.

But, not working on a few servers, and returns the below error/warning

> WARNING: [06:05:42][Get-DbaAgentJob] Failure | The value's length for key 'Data Source' exceeds its limit of '128'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.    What version are you running?   1.1.6 works as expected.

Comment: This isn't an error, it's a warning. Use the `-Verbose` switch and it may tell you _which_ job is throwing this warning, which will get you closer to finding the source.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while executing dbatools Backup-dbaDatabase.

Fortunately, it was executing properly on my laptop but while I was executing it on the server it was failing with the same error you pointed out.

That's why it was easy for me to identify that it is PowerShell version that is not compatible with latest build of dbatools module.

So, upgrading PowerShell to latest version fixed the error.

Thanks!